# delete item from main list if its empty in C# Entity

Tags: c#, sql-server

In this code I check if Unit stock is empty for the same product Id which I selected, then I can delete product, but if so, I also want to delete Product Group for all products that have the same group Id after ensuring they all are empty. What should I do?

[here are my model classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHqDA.png)

```
public int Get(int? id)
{
    JalkahoitolaEntities entities = new JalkahoitolaEntities();
    List<int?> items = (from o in entities.Recieved_ammounts
                        where o.ProductId == id
                        select o.UnitStock).ToList();

    if (items.Sum() == 0 || items.Sum() == null)
    {
        Product ProductToBeRemoved = (from o in entities.Products
                                        where o.ProductId == id
                                        select o).First();
        entities.Products.Remove(ProductToBeRemoved);
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }

    entities.Dispose();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You want to delete `ProductGroup` if `UnitStock` of it's childs(Product) was empty ?

Comment: Why using "items.Sum() == null"?

Comment: Are you getting some exception ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to delete `ProductGroup` then you are missing with deletion of `ProductGroup` .Update your code to add Deletion logic for `ProductGroup` as well.

**Retrieve Prodcut to be removed**

```
   Product ProductToBeRemoved = (from o in entities.Products
                                    where o.ProductId == id
                                    select o).First();
    entities.Products.Remove(ProductToBeRemoved);
```

**Delete `ProductGroup` based on `ProductToBeRemoved GroupId`**

```
    ProductGroup ProductGroupToBeRemoved = (from o in entities.ProductGroup
                                    where o.GroupId== ProductToBeRemoved .GroupId
                                    select o).First();
    entities.ProductGroup.Remove(ProductGroupToBeRemoved);
```

Then call the `SaveChanges()`

**UPDATE** : After reading OP's comment.

You don't need to write multiple queries for this. Try using some thing like

```
var prodGroupsToRemove = (from ra in entities.Recieved_ammounts
          join prod  in entities.Products on ra.ProductId  equals prod.ProductId            
          join prodGrp in entities.ProductGroup on prod.GroupId equals prodGrp.GroupID             
          where (ra.UnitStock > 0)
          select new { GroupId = prodGrp.GroupId , ProductId = prod.ProductId}).ToList();
```

Above query will return a list of `GroupsID,ProductId` you want to delete.

**Note** You need to filter out Products/Group based on result to delete.This might not work simple copy/paste, You may need to update it a bit.

Comment: what I want is,lets say we have product group which include 10 products,  if you want to delete Product group, you should check each product if unit stock is empty or not, if empty then we can delete product group.

Comment: See updated answer, Both solutions should work as per your requirement.